# How to get another field for authorized user in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

There are some fields in table `Users`: `id, password, language`.

For authorized user I can get `id` field like as: `Auth::user()->id`.

But how I can get `language` field? Where is it stored?

Comment: Please add database model here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Auth::user()` will grab the current logged in user. If you were to `dd(Auth::user())` you would see that it is just returning the eloquent object. This means if you want to get another field(s) from the database on your logged in user you would just do

`Auth::user()->language`

The user object would be the same as doing

```
$user = \App\User::find(1);
dd($user->language);
```

Comment: I get error: `Trying to get property of non-object` when I try: `Auth::user()->language`

Comment: How I can keep a global objeect of authorized user?

Comment: @Putin Where exactly are you trying to get the `language` property?

Answer (score 0):

When you try `Auth::user();` code you will get all the details of Authenticated user information.from that you can get data which you need. this should work for anyone 100% sure.

```
$user = Auth::user();
dd($user->language); or  dd($user->name);
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".